# kernel - booting address. Why?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel

#### Context:

Reading how a kernel boots.

I was on that page:
http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/2239

and it says the kernel loads at 0x10000.

#### Question:

why this address?

Comment: Because the BIOS wants it so...

Comment: do note that the article is way too old and basically *nothing* mentioned in the article holds anymore. Even the images have been for more than decade been too large to be loaded at that address.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: Ah ? So, what is the current rule ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an area of 480.5 KiB from 0x00007E00 to 0x0007FFFF that is guaranteed to be free RAM available for the operating system.
It's important to know that [not all physical addresses are free, usable RAM](http://wiki.osdev.org/Memory_Map_%28x86%29). Some are reserved for BIOS data, to be used as video memory, or other reasons.

It's not unusual to see cheap BIOSes and hardware that ignores standards or try to do smart hacks but end up breaking things. This region of memory is safe from all the shenanigans, it's the nice and obvious place to load your data, and indeed it seems to have worked well.

As you may know, the boot sector is typically located from 0x00007C00 to 0x00007DFF, and as your article mentions, Linux relocates this sector to 0x00090000, then loads the rest of the kernel starting from 0x00010000. This is a good location because it's the largest (almost half a MiB) chunk of RAM in low memory that is guaranteed to be free for use.